# How do I update the azimuth of orientation of the Android emulator?

Tags: android, orientation, emulation, telnet, azimuth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I emulate a compass on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376512/can-i-emulate-a-compass-on-android)

I'm developing an Android application whose display depends on the orientation (azimuth specifically) of the phone. I'd like to test the application using the Android emulator, and so I need to change the orientation of the emulator dynamically through its telnet interface.

I can change its GPS position by issuing commands of the form: geo fix 34 56

However, I can't work out how to do the same for its azimuth. Is this possible, and if so how?

Thanks for any help, Martin

Comment: I think this is a duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376512/can-i-emulate-a-compass-on-android

Comment: Thanks - not quite the answer I was expecting or hoping for, but at least I know! I was reduced to moving my PC around to get the emulator orientation to change.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple .You have to just press ctrl+F11 to change orientation when emulator is running.

Comment: Hi - thanks but this not what I meant. I do not mean the horizontal/vertical orientation of the phone. I mean the azimuth: this is one of the three values that comes back from the call to the Orientation sensor:

Comment: orientationSensor = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Orientation);
sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, orientationSensor, SensorDelay.Normal);I mean sensorEvent.Values[0]

Comment: Sorry - I hit return before completing this comment. I meant, if you have code along these lines:

orientationSensor = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Orientation);
sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, orientationSensor, SensorDelay.Normal);

When the listener detects a SensorEvent, then the OnSensorChanged(Sensor sensorEvent) method can retrieve the new azimuth as sensorEvent.Values[0]

What I would like to do, if I can, is to make the emulator fire a series of SensorEvents, by using the telnet interface. Is this clearer?